# ES6 - Value of a variable in template string does not increment

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am dynamically adding rows to a table on a button click. The HTML is wrapped inside `` and the value that has to be incremented on each row addition is wrapped inside template string. Even though when the value of the variable increments, it does not show up the updated value rendered in HTML via the backticks and template string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <table class="MsoNormalTable" id="table1" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 22.3pt;">
                <td style="width: 128.55pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="171">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">FUND:</span></strong></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 177.2pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="236">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_benefit_type1}<br /> <br /> <br /> </span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 22.3pt;">
                <td style="width: 128.55pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="171">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">NAME OF EMPLOYEE:</span></strong></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 177.2pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="236">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.employee.name1}<br /> <br /> <br /> </span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20.7pt;">
                <td style="width: 128.55pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 20.7pt;" valign="top" width="171">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">EMPLOYEE NUMBER:</span></strong></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 177.2pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 20.7pt;" valign="top" width="236">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_employee_number1}<br /> <br /> </span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <table class="MsoNormalTable" id="table2" style="margin-left: -4.75pt; border-collapse: collapse; border: none;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 29.65pt;">
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Surname</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">First Names</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Gender</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Date of Birth</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Relationship</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Share of Benefit</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Contact No.</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 89.5pt;">
                <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_surname1}</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_first_name1}&nbsp;</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_gender1}</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_date_of_birth1}</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_relationship1}</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_share_of_benefit1}</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_contact_number1}</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <button id="add-rows">Add Rows</button>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var i = 2;

        $('#add-rows').bind('click', function() {
            $('#table1 tbody').append(rowForTableOne);
            $('#table2 tbody').append(rowForTableTwo);
            i++;
        }); 

        var rowForTableOne = `<tr style="height: 22.3pt;">
                    <td style="width: 128.55pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="171">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">FUND:</span></strong></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 177.2pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="236">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_benefit_type${parseInt(i)}}<br /> <br /> <br /> </span></strong></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 22.3pt;">
                    <td style="width: 128.55pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="171">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">NAME OF EMPLOYEE:</span></strong></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 177.2pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 22.3pt;" valign="top" width="236">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.employee.name${i}}<br /> <br /> <br /> </span></strong></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 20.7pt;">
                    <td style="width: 128.55pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 20.7pt;" valign="top" width="171">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">EMPLOYEE NUMBER:</span></strong></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 177.2pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 20.7pt;" valign="top" width="236">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_employee_number${i}}<br /> <br /> </span></strong></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;


         var rowForTableTwo = `<tr style="height: 29.65pt;">
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Surname</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">First Names</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Gender</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Date of Birth</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Relationship</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Share of Benefit</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 29.65pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">Contact No.</span></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 89.5pt;">
                    <td style="border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top: none; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_surname${i}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_first_name${i}}&nbsp;</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_gender${i}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_date_of_birth${i}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_relationship${i}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_share_of_benefit${i}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height: 89.5pt;" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" align="center"><span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_contact_number${i}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;

    });


</script>

</html>
```

A small glimpse of how I try to use the value of `i`

```
<span style="color: black;">#{u_beneficiary_record_id.u_dependant_contact_number${i}}</span>
```

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your i variable is incremented. The problem is, when your HTML is added to your rowForTable* strings, i equals 2 and when it changes, it doesn't affect your string.

You should put the code that generates the HTML in a separate function and pass your increment as a parameter :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // the increment variable was renamed to avoid confusion
    var increment = 2;

    $('#add-rows').bind('click', function() {
        // calling the appendRow function and passing the increment as a parameter : 
        appendRow(increment++);
    }); 

    // the fonction that will generate your HTML code with a variable 'i' passed as parameter :
    function appendRow(i) {
        var rowForTableOne = ...; // put your previous code here
        var rowForTableTwo = ...; // put your previous code here

        // appending the rows to your document : 
        $('#table1 tbody').append(rowForTableOne);
        $('#table2 tbody').append(rowForTableTwo);

    }



});
```